# Como salvar no MySql todo dado inseriado em um form-control

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Galera, como posso fazer um script para salvar todo dado logo após sua inserção. No caso a view seria essa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após digitar e teclar enter o dado já seria salvo no bd.

Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Aqui o trecho do meu form:

```
<!-- Domain start -->
    <label for="domain_input">Domains</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="domain_input" name="domain_input" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add domain" required="required" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20}"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button id="add_domain_button" class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <table id="domain_list" class="table table-responsive">

    </table>

</div>
<!-- Domain end -->
```

Acredito que eu não esteja sabendo "pegar" os dados inseridos nessa table e nem como realizar essa inserção (no caso jogar os dados para a controller de alguma forma (post talvez?)).

Tentei com algumas funções de keyevent mas sem sucesso (falha minha acredito).

Edit1@

Consegue com alert mostrar alguns dados inseridos na tabela com o seguinte code

```
<script>
  function testa() { 
    $('#lc_searchresult > table > tbody > tr').each(function() {
    var data = $(this).find('td').text();
    alert(data);        
}); }
</script>
```

Porém, parece falhar as vezes e vir campo em branco.

A dúvida continua em como eu farei para salvar os dados no banco assim que o usuário inserir um item. Inseriu - salvou.

Comment: Está bastante ampla sua pergunta. Não que ela não seja boa. Uma solução, bastante usada, seria usar o AJAX. Com o javascript você "chama" um arquivo php que salva esses dados e atualiza uma div. Como se fosse um "chat". Dá uma pesquisada, tem muitos exemplos na internet. Se você tiver um problema mais específico ai você posta ele aqui que será mais fácil de te ajudar.

Comment: Acho que não soube me explicar, eu achei alguns exemplos, mas realmente não sou bom com js e queria continuar escrevendo código que eu consiga entender. Basicamente eu quero realizar uma query e salvar no banco cada vez que o usuário inserir algo nesse campo. Já achei "n" exemplos, inclusive no momento estou tentando, <script>  
$("input[name=domain_input]").keypress(function(){
    $.post( "<?=base_url()?>protocol/add_domain", { dado: $("input[name=domain_input]").val() } );
});
 </script> porém sigo não conseguindo trabalhar direito com esses dados do table.

Comment: Entendi. Coloque esse código que você comentou aqui, na pergunta. Vai ajudar alguém a te responder. Já salvei aqui nos favoritos.

Comment: Se ninguém responder até amanhã. Eu farei um exemplo para você.

Comment: Fico grato pela ajuda amigo, tenha uma ótima noite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pergunta não inclui jQuery mas usar esse framework as vezes facilita o trabalho, então uma forma que você poderia fazer o que quer é a seguinte:

1. Coletar os dados do `form` : [Olhe esse post sobre `serializeArray()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/150042/como-enviar-dados-de-um-formul%C3%A1rio-sem-bot%C3%A3o-submit-e-sem-atualizar-a-p%C3%A1gina/150055#150055)
2. Convertê-los para o formato JSON: *Explicado abaixo*
3. Enviá-los via AJAX para o PHP
4. No script PHP convertê-los para array com `json_decode()` e salvar no BD
5. Se obtiver resposta de sucesso do PHP, insere o item na página.

### OBS:

#### PASSO 1

Os dados coletados do form com `serializeArray()` estarão no seguinte formato

```
[ { name: "domain-input", value: "meuConteúdo" }, 
  { name: "domain-input2", value: "conteúdo qualquer" } 
]
```

#### PASSO 2

```
var unindexed_array = $("form").serializeArray();  // Coleta os dados do form
var jsonData = {}

$.each(unindexed_array, function(i, item) {
    // Para cada item em 'unindexed_array', fazer o que está aqui dentro.
    jsonData[item["name"]] = item["value"];  // salva 
});
```

Depois disso, `jsonData` estará no seguinte formato (JSON):

```
jsonData = { 
     "domain-input" : "meuConteúdo",
     "domain-input2" : "conteúdo qualquer"
 }
```

#### PASSO 3

```
$.ajax({
        data: jsonData,           // dados a serem enviados
        dataType: "json",         // Formato do dado **recebido como resposta do servidor**.  html, json, text ...
        method: "post",           // post ou get
        url: "myPHPscript.php",   // url invocada
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // Executado em caso de sucesso.
            alert(data+" "+textStatus+" "+jqXHR+" ");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Executado em caso de erro.
            alert(jqXHR+" "+ textStatus+" "+ errorThrown);
            error();
        }
    });
```

Você pode ver mais [nesse post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/268245/enviando-vari%C3%A1veis-no-ajax-para-o-php)  ou na [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) do jQuery.

#### PASSO 4

Receber os dados em PHP com `json_decode()`.

Arquivo PHP:

```
$domain-input = json_decode($_POST["domain-input"], true);
$domain-input2 = json_decode($_POST["domain-input2"], true);
// Salva no BD

if (sucesso) { 
    $resposta_array['status'] = 'success';
} else {
    $resposta_array['status'] = 'error';
}

echo json_encode($resposta_array);
```

Espero ter ajudado.

---

### EDIÇÃO

No **PASSO 3**, para garantir que os dados passados estejam no formato JSON, você pode usar a função `JSON.stringify` do Javascript. O que ela faz é converter o argumento passado à ela para uma string JSON - o que já era de se esperar pelo seu nome hehe. Ainda, acrescentar `contentType: "application/json"` ao objeto de opções passado à função `$.ajax`. Então:

```
$.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json",  
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),                   // dados a serem enviados agora com a certeza de estarem em JSON.
        dataType: "json",                 // Formato do dado **recebido como resposta do servidor**.  html, json, text ...
        method: "post",                   // post ou get
        url: "myPHPscript.php",           // url invocada
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // Executado em caso de sucesso.
            alert(data+" "+textStatus+" "+jqXHR+" ");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Executado em caso de erro.
            alert(jqXHR+" "+ textStatus+" "+ errorThrown);
            error();
        }
    });
```

No **PASSO 4**, o correto seria

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');    // Altera o cabecalho para que o retorno seja em JSON

$aDados = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true); // Ver comentário abaixo.

// Verificar se foi recebido dados
// Usar assim: $aDados['domain-input']
// Salvar no BD

if (sucesso) { 
    $resposta_array['status'] = 'success';
} else {
    $resposta_array['status'] = 'error';
}

echo json_encode($resposta_array);         // Converte para JSON e imprime na página.
```

A expressão `file_get_contents("php://input")` é usada para coletar os dados enviados pelo AJAX porque `$_POST` estará vazio já que o `content-type` do pedido ([leia mais aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)) será `application/json` (passado pela função ajax) o que não é suportado pela variável `$_PHP` segundo a sua [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

Um problema causado por isso (e que talvez não faça diferença para a maioria dos casos) é que `php://input` não estará disponível caso o `form` seja enviado usando `enctype="multipart/form-data"` o que significa que não será possível incluir, por exemplo, uploads de imagens. Para o seu caso, não parece haver problemas já que você enviará apenas textos.

Comment: Ótima resposta.

Comment: Cara, sua resposta foi simplesmente fantástica. Existe muito material sobre isso na internet, mas para quem está começando no mundo do js fica tudo um quanto confuso. Novamente, muito obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que a resposta te ajudou. Fiz algumas edições importantes a fim de funcionar. Qualquer dúvida pergunta aqui e eu ou mais alguém pode tentar te ajudar.