# Atualizar variavel PHP com Jquery usando requisição AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

estou com um problema relacionado a HTML, Jquery e PHP, vou tentar passar o maximo de informações.
Eu tenho uma pagina PHP que tem que ir e voltar com as variáveis e é tipo um passo a passo, onde cada passo manda para o próximo os seus dados para filtrar as tabelas no banco de dados MySQL. O meu problema é que a variável vai mas não volta. Então eu to incluindo no projeto requisições AJAX, onde ao eu clicar no botão eu mando para a mesma página via POST no JQuery os valores. O problema é que a variável não está pegando esse valor. Teria como eu setar essa variavel depois do click no botão, ou passar esse valor de outra forma? Vou mandar os códigos.

```js
console.log($("#prox1"));


$("#prox1").click(function(event) {
console.log("Ok");
console.log($("#curso").val());
console.log($("#turno").val());
console.log($("input[name='tipoLab']:checked").val());
  var dados1 = {curso: $("#curso").val(), turno: $("#turno").val(), tipoLab: $("input[name='tipoLab']:checked").val()};

  $.post('../processamento/index.php', dados1, function() {
    console.log("Fui e voltei");
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="ls-steps-content" id="step1">
            <?php $sql ="SELECT cursos from cursos order by cursos asc";
            $resultado = conecta( $maquina , $usuario, $senha, $banco, $sql );?>
            <div class="ls-custom-select selectEtapa1">
              <select id="curso" name="curso" class="ls-select">
                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled"> Cursos </option>
                <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
                  $curso = $row["cursos"];
                  ?>
                  <option value="<?=$curso?>"><?=$curso?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="ls-custom-select selectEtapa1">
                <select id="turno" name="turno" class="ls-select">
                  <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled"> Turno </option>
                  <option value="Manha"> Manhã </option>
                  <option value="noite"> Noite </option>

                </select>
              </div>
              <fieldset>
                <!-- Exemplo com Radio button -->
                <div class="ls-label col-md-5">
                  <p>Escolha uma das plataformas:</p>
                  <label class="ls-label-text">
                    <input type="radio" name="tipoLab" value="labinfo">
                    Laboratório de informática
                  </label>
                  <label class="ls-label-text">
                    <input type="radio" name="tipoLab" value="labEng">
                    Laboratorio de Engenharia
                  </label>
                  <label class="ls-label-text">
                    <input type="radio" name="tipoLab" value="labSau">
                    Laboratório de Saúde
                  </label>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <div class="ls-actions-btn">
                <form method="post" action="index.php">
                  <input type="hidden" name="curso">
                  <button type="submit" id="prox1" href="#" class="ls-btn-primary ls-float-right" data-action="next">Próximo</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ls-steps-content" id="step2">
              <?php $_POST["curso"] ?>
              <div class="ls-actions-btn">
                <a href="#" class="ls-btn" data-action="prev">Anterior</a>
                <a href="#" class="ls-btn-primary ls-float-right" data-action="next">Próximo</a>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Se alguem tiver outra forma de me ajudar pode ser tambem, só preciso de ficar indo e voltando com essas variáveis quando o usuário quiser.

Obrigado desde já

Comment: Acredito que o erro esteja ao pegar esses dados e não no envio

Comment: qual variavel você está passando? onde ela deveria retornar?

Comment: Ela deveria retornar nesse trecho
<div class="ls-steps-content" id="step2">
              <?= $_POST["curso"] ?>
Ja que eu mandei ela via POST pra essa mesma pagina no AJAX, no Inspector, fui no Network e esta lá os parâmetros do POST então não sei porque ela não esta recebendo os mesmos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou tentar ser breve com a resposta. Vejo alguns erros que estão impedindo o funcionamento correto:

- A página está sendo **atualizada** ao fazer o pedido AJAX. Para evitar isso na função *callback* do *event handler* `click()`, acrescente o código `event.preventDefault()`, pois o evento `click` está sendo disparado por um botão `submit`de um formulário.
- Se você estiver recebendo uma resposta JSON, precisa incluir `"post"` como **quarto** parâmetro da função `post()`
- Sobre "`O meu problema é que a variável vai mas não volta.`", só pra ficar mais claro caso essa seja sua dúvida também: a variável não retorna. O que vai retornar é um **novo valor** (que pode ser igual ao enviado) enviado pela página invocada - no caso `../processamento/index.php`. Mas não faz muito sentido retornar o mesmo valor já que você já tem esse valor no jQuery. É mais rápido só retornar uma mensagem de sucesso.
- Não sei se entendi bem, mas de `"onde ao eu clicar no botão eu mando para a mesma página via POST"` eu entendi que você está enviando o pedido para a mesma página do formulário. Se isso estiver correto, o que será retornado pelo servidor será a mesma **página HTML** que faz o pedido (sem as alterações feitas pelo usuário). Mas se você quiser retornar apenas dados "simples", pode retornar esses dados em JSON pelo PHP - ou ainda de outra forma.

Eu acho sempre bom converter os dados com `JSON.stringfy(meusDados)` antes de enviá-los ao servidor, porque o PHP tem algumas restrições quando trabalhando com JSON. 
Para citar algumas retiradas da [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

- Nomes e valores *string* têm que estar entre aspas duplas. Ex: `'{"nome": "valor", "idade": 32}'`
- Não pode ter vírgula após o último ítem. Ex: `'{"vouDarErro":"vírgulaSobrando",}'`

Espero ter ajudado. Se ficou confuso comenta aí embaixo.

Comment: Deixe tentar ser mais claro, Eu tenho um sistema de agendamento de laboratorios certo? Na primeira pagina eu pego o Curso, Turno e o Tipo do Laboratorio. O que eu quero e pegar os values que foram escolhidos para fazer um SELECT no MySQL das salas do tipo do laboratório escolhido entendeu? Então eu preciso que esses 3 values sejam guardados em uma variavel PHP que eu posso usar na mesma página para começar a fazer minhas buscas no banco. Ex.: 
values = tipoLab: "LabInfo";
<?php $TipoLab = $_POST["tipoLab"];
$sql = "SELECT salas FROM labs WHERE tipoLab = '$TipoLab'";
Isso na mesma pagina

Comment: Você quer fazer o pedido via AJAX para a mesma página PHP que contém o form?

Comment: Isso, se possível sem precisar recarregar, mas caso seja necessário e melhor que nada kk

Comment: A função do AJAX é pedir por recursos (páginas, dados, imagens etc) assincronamente, ou seja, "sem atualizar a página". Porém, no seu caso, acho que não faz sentido permitir que o PHP retorne a mesma página que contém o formulário inteira. Porque, assim, o servidor PHP irá renderizar a página e retornar um HTML que será igual a página em que você já está (exceto os dados que você está carregando do BD). Sendo que o que você quer são apenas os novos dados do BD. Resumindo, no seu caso, o retorno do pedido AJAX deveria retornar apenas os novos dados e não toda a página HTML novamente

Comment: Você pode criar um `if` no início do seu arquivo PHP que verifica se dados estão sendo recebidos. Se sim, ao invés de executar a página normalmente, ele executa apenas o bloco de código desse `if`. Mas acho melhor você usar outra página para buscar os dados PHP porque ela só precisa retornar os novos dados (não a estrutura HTML da página). Talvez este post te ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297033/como-salvar-no-mysql-todo-dado-inseriado-em-um-form-control/297125#297125